# How to scroll/swipe in Appium tests using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, appium, python-appium

I am trying to scroll / swipe from ft. to m. in my Appium with Python test.
Accessibility id for feet is `ft.` and for metric is `m.`

Here is the code snippet I am trying to use to do this but the `ft.` doesn't switch to `m.`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ACCESSIBILITY_ID, "ft.")))
start = driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("ft.")
time.sleep(1)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ACCESSIBILITY_ID, "m.")))
end = driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("m.")
time.sleep(1)
TouchAction(driver).press(start).move_to(end).release().perform()
```

[image]

How can I change it to m.? (In the picture below I have played with the swipe but I can't be dependent on the coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for each in range(1, 2):
            driver.swipe(500, 1700, 500, 1000, 400)
```

Change the value on for loop according to to the swipes required